# Why is this regex str_replace not working?

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to use a regular expression to replace any domain in a string with another domain but it isn't working yet.

I tested the RegEx part on regexpal.com and it seems to be working.

Here is my code:

```
$itemdesc = str_replace("([a-z0-9\-]+).(com|net|org|co|cm|info|cc)\s\i","Example.com",$itemdesc);
```

Please Help!  Thanks in advance

Comment: Since when does `str_replace` accept a regex pattern? P.S. I think you want to escape the dot in the pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need delimiters and preg_replace:

```
$itemdesc = preg_replace("/([a-z0-9\-]+)\.(com|net|org|co|cm|info|cc)/si","Example.com",$itemdesc);
```

Note the slashes at either end - the modifiers following the last delimiter

Also note, the delimiters can be any character - try to use a character that isn't used in your regular expression, otherwise it'll need to be escaped everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

str_replace does not take a regular expression as parameter, you have to use [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)